# Why is this css page curl shadow not working?

Tags: css, webkit

The :before & :after are in front when they shouldn't be!  I take it the problem has something do with the z-indexes, but I don't see it. Thought I copied [this](http://matthamm.com/box-shadow-curl.html) code  exactly.. I must be missing something, what?

http://jsfiddle.net/wije/nxVTk/

Chrome 15.0.874.121

Edit: What I'm trying to acheive is the same as [this](http://matthamm.com/box-shadow-curl.html), i.e. a two angled shadows beneath the wrapper div, giving it "curly page" effect.

Comment: I see box shadows on Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `z-index: 1` from `.wrapper`:

http://jsfiddle.net/nxVTk/17/